# .htaccess rewrite rule for CSS request

Tags: php, .htaccess, website, rewrite, url

Good Morning,

I am trying to create RewriteRule for all request for css file within my website to css/filename.css. The procedure is all css files within my website store only in mydomain.com/css/filename.css, but some page I wrote the rule and direct browser via friendly url to mydomain.com/services/index.html, then the request for css file could not find.

Anybody has experience please help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Match on any request that ends with `.css` and rewrite it to be `/css/filename.css`?  This should do it:

```
RewriteRule \.css$ /css/filename.css [NC]
```

Don't forget to add `RewriteEngine On` if you don't already have it.

*Edit: I added the NC flag to the rewrite, to catch mixed case, ie: .Css or .CSS*